# Adding to JS objects in awkward places

Tags: javascript, object

If I have something like the following JS object as an example:

```
self.JSON = {
    "key1": ["1", "2", "paul"],
    "key2": true,
    "key3": {
         "key3.1": true,
         "key3.2": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
    "key4": false,
    "key5": ["10", "9", "17", "4"]
    }
}
```

How could I use Javascript to put the following:

```
"newKey": {
    "newKey1": true,
    "newKey2": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
},
```

Into this object between two keys, for example, between "key2" & "key3" whilst still maintaining the existing structure so that the final object would look like this:

```
self.JSON = {
    "key1": ["1", "2", "paul"],
    "key2": true,
    "newKey": {
        "newKey1": true,
        "newKey2": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
    },
    "key3": {
         "key3.1": true,
         "key3.2": ["yes", "no", "maybe"]
    "key4": false,
    "key5": ["10", "9", "17", "4"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Object keys are unordered. Or rather: there's no guarantee that keys/values will appear in the "correct" order when you loop over them.

Comment: [`self.JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) might be a dangerous name for an object.

Comment: That's not json. json is a string representation of a javascript object. you just have plain old javascript. And since it's just javascript, you use plain old javascript array/object access methods to change that structure.

Comment: why do you need this particular order? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript objects are unordered. You can't control where to place the keys.

As specified in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Comment: You can link to a particular section in [this version of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/).